# How do I Super Jump?

Tags: splatoon

I see people on my map jumping to the middle of the arena, and this Super Jump is mentioned in the items store. How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just click on the Wii U Gamepad on another players name, or click a [squid beacon](http://splatoon.wikia.com/wiki/Squid_Beakon).

In an image, on the right you can click the nameplates:

[image: Gamepad]

Comment: You can also click on the squids on the map. (I didn't know you could click the names!) Also, you can jump to the spawn point from anywhere.